# Which options exist for a Macbook air (2010) SSD upgrade?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, ssd, hardware-recommendation

I Know OCZ has released an SSD for the MBA, what other brands sell this kind of hardware?

Comment: Note that he mentioned the MacBook Air, which does not use a standard 2.5" drive, but a custom form factor. So a specialized part is necessary in this case.

Comment: Lol oops, i completely missed out on the "air" part in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's Other World Computing (OWC, also known as macsales.com) that offers 3rd party SSDs for the MacBook Air. They're based on the fairly widespread Sandforce controllers (also used by OCZ). You can find them [here](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Aura_Pro_Air_2010).

The only other option I've heard about is RunCore, which [announced in May](http://9to5mac.com/2012/05/30/runcore-adds-another-ssd-upgrade-option-to-macbook-air-owners/) it was going to make a MBA compatible SSD, but as far as I can tell, nothing's been released yet, and it may only be compatible with 2011 and later models.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to upgrade my late 2010 MacBook air with an SSD from [OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Air-Retina).

The first one worked for 3-4 hours and then the system wouldn't recognize it.  I RMA'd it.  The system wouldn't even recognize the replacement.  The original SSD continues to work fine.

Answer (score -1):

[OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Aura_Pro_Air_2010) has an upgrade available for all models of the MacBook Air; I've never used them for an Air, but have been very happy with their 2.5" SSDs in a variety of other Macs including MBPs and Pros.