# How to choose a compatible SSD replacement/adapter for Macbook Air mid-2011 13"?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade, third-party

What parameters should I consider when choosing an after-market replacement for an original SSD in Macbook Air 13" mid-2011 A1369?

Looks like there are third-party adapters available now (eg [QNine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MXW9AMS)). What aspects should I consider in deciding whether the adapter will be compatible to:

- a replacement SSD (eg. [Samsung 860 EVO M.2 SATA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07822SVMS))
- the Macbook Air

**Is "proprietary connector / firmware" still an issue today for SSDs on 2011 Air, which can be a stopper here?**

**Are the following parameters conclusive on understanding compatibility between the adapter and the SSD itself: form factor (M.2 2280), interface (SATA B-key)?**

---

My initial research gives varying opinions:

- it needs to be [single-sided SSD](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1NCHVE0FE08EA/), but unclear what is actually meant (eg is the above Samsung actually single-sided)
- [some users believe](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225075/finding-suitable-ssd-for-my-macbook-air#comment273388_225079) that SSDs which are not from Apple nor from OWC will not work, even if they fit connectors properly
- OWC SSDs are supported [because they have Sandforce controllers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/56469/54644)
- [someone managed](https://www.amazon.com/ask/answer/MxK8T4B7PNJVN1/) the 1TB version of Samsung to work with this adapter
- [difficult physical fit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225310/54644) for 2012 models (I wonder whether they have a different layout/space constraints than 2011)

Comment: https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-air/2010-2011

Comment: @user3439894 I'm aware about OWC, but they are much more expensive (x2) than QNine adapter + Samsung SSD. The question is whether eg QNine+Samsung can be equivalent solution.